# Which of the two usage patterns regarding Dictionary should be preferred in general?

Tags: c#, performance, exception, dictionary

In the code base I've been working on, I find usage pattern like this:

```
If (dict.ContainsKey(key)) // dict is of type IDictionary
{
  throw ...;
}
else
{
  dict.Add(key, …);
}
```

This involves two searching procedure invocations (`ContainsKey` + `[]`/`Add`), whichever branch the code takes. I’m wondering whether the following pattern would be more efficient and should be preferred in general. It involves only one searching procedure invocation, but additionally relies on the exception system to work, which is expected to have some runtime overhead.

```
try
{
  dict.Add(key, …);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
  throw ...;
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should be reserved for exceptional circumstances. I feel like a collision in a dictionary would be an expected thing to happen, so it feels like an abuse of the exception system to me.

Comment: Side note: are you aware that `catch { throw; }` does precisely nothing?

Comment: Also, the `TryGet` function is available for this case.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Indeed. Thanks for the mention.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Just updated the question. I don't actually need the value if the key-value pair exists already. So, I don't think `TryGet()` applies here.

Comment: Ah, I see. The question, then, is whether the "key already exists" situation is *exceptional*. I'm assuming yes, since you're throwing an exception when it happens.. so I would say it's fine to let `dict.Add` throw, and catch/wrap the exception if it fails.

Comment: Which would be faster in the non-exceptional case, since you're only accessing the dictionary once.

Comment: If you're after efficiency you should avoid anything throwing or catching. Exception handling code is many orders of magnitude slower than non-exceptional code. You should read Eric Lippert's excellent article on exceptions - https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/.

Comment: And if you really want a good solid answer to this question you should provide us with a [mcve]. Then we can test and benchmark all the possible approaches.

Comment: @Enigmativity depends on how often you throw. At some point, the overhead of checking every time will be greater than the cost of just throwing on failure.

Comment: Either pattern is fine, because your program should not be relying on exceptions for flow control in the first place. I.e. these exceptions should occur only when there's a bug in the program, and in that case it really doesn't matter which is faster. If the exception can be thrown regularly, then you need to fix the design so it can operate exception-free even when the key is already present, in a manner similar to that which `TryGetValue()` uses.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: _"depends on how often you throw"_ --  you are correct, but that misses the point. If in a correctly operating program this code throws at all, the design is wrong. Using exceptions for flow control instead of limiting them to actual exceptional scenarios, e.g. coding error or user error, is a very bad practice. And in the actual exceptional scenarios, the frequency had better be low by design.

Comment: Yes, my point is that this may be a "user error" situation. In which case, I would use exceptions. If it's not exceptional, then I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If the function's post-conditions cannot be met when the key already exists in the IDictionary (meaning it's not safe to return and keep running the program's current flow), then by all means go with the latter approach. One less lookup, a "happy path" that has almost no runtime cost and no chance left for accidental misuse/discard of an "error code" return value.

I assume you need to throw a specific exception type or message if that happens. Otherwise, just loose the try...catch block.